# Integrating BizTalk 2016 and Dynamics 365 on premises

Tags: dynamics-crm, biztalk

I need to integrate BizTalk 2016 and Dynamics 365 on premises. Is there any software that could accelerate this? Does anyone know where I could find examples of how this can be achieved?

Comment: I don't have a problem to describe. Opinions are what I'm after. I can decide for myself if they are opinionated or spam etc. Is there a different site to get the answers I seek?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, here's the deal, this really isn't something you just do...

While D365 has a full OData base Rest API, plan to spend a fair amount of time learning those patterns, then even more in discussions with the business on exactly what they want to do.

BizTalk + OData + Rest is pretty basic is is just JSON over Http.  In BizTalk you would use the JSON pipeline components and wCF-WebHttp Adapter.

Well, since there's no comment and there is nothing wrong with this answer, the Downvote should be ignored as invalid and misleading.